# Take mean of feature set using openSMILE audio feature extractor

Tags: audio, cmd, frameworks, feature-extraction, feature-selection

My problem is taking mean of all features from different frames in one sample .wav file. I am trying cFunctionals in "chroma_fft.conf" file which belongs to latest OpenEar framework. For best explanation, i am writing these essential codes which i wrote in "chroma_fft.conf" and it is shown below;

```
[componentInstances:cComponentManager]
instance[functL1].type = cFunctionals

[functL1:cFunctional]
reader.dmLevel = chroma
writer.dmLevel = func 
frameMode = full
frameSize=0
frameStep=0
functionalsEnabled = Means
Means.amean = 1

[csvSink:cCsvSink]
reader.dmLevel = func
..NOT-IMPORTANT......
..NOT-IMPORTANT......
```

However, when i run from command prompt in windows, i got error;
"(ERROR) [1] in configManager : base instance of field 'functL1.reader.dmInstance' not found in configmanager!"

Very similar code is running succesfully from "emo_large.conf" but this code got error. If any body knows how to use OpenSmile audio feature extractor, can give advice or answer why it has error and how to use "cFunctionals" properly to take mean, variance, moments etc. of large feature sets.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have a typo in

[functL1:cFunctional]

which should be

[functL1:cFunctional**s**]

I admit the error message

"(ERROR) [1] in configManager : base instance of field 'functL1.reader.dmInstance' not found in configmanager!"

is not intutive, but it refers to the fact that openSMILE expects a configuration section functL1 of type cFunctional**s** in the config to read the mandatory (sub-)field functL1.reader.dmInstance, which it then cannot find, because the section (due to the typo) is not defined.

Cheers,
Florian